# CXX0030: ошибка: невозможно вычислить выражение

Tags: c++

t_val   0x00000000 <Неправильный указатель> char *CXX0030: ошибка: невозможно вычислить выражение

Вот часть кода, в котором ошибка :

```
size_t check_cin = 0; 
    cout << "Введите начальное время в формте - 00:00:00,000 час/минута/секунда/миллисекунда\n";
    string newtime;
    char* t_val;
    int t_size = 12;
    do 
    {
    cin.getline(t_val, t_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < t_size; i++)
    {
        if((i == 2  && t_val[i] == ':') || (i == 5 && t_val[i] == ':') || (i == 8 && t_val[i] == ','))
        {
            newtime[i] = t_val[i];
            ++check_cin;
        }
        if((i != 2 || i != 5 || i != 8) && (t_val[i] >= '0' && t_val[i] <= '9'))
        {
            newtime[i] = t_val[i];
            ++check_cin;
        }
    }
    if(check_cin != t_size)
        check_cin = 0;
    }
    while(check_cin != t_size);
```

Кстати это плохой код? Как можно было бы лучше реализовать?

Comment: А что в результате Вы хотите получить? (ошибка компиляции, как я понял, уже есть).

И как следует реагировать на ошибки в формате?

Что делать, если файл вообще пустой?

И т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это жуткий код. Если бы мне нужно было сделать решение в лоб (максимально быстро, но грязно), то я бы написал такой код (я убрал ввод):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    std::string st = "12:22:32.123";
    const char * ss = st.c_str();
    int h,m,s,ms;
    sscanf(ss, "%d:%d:%d.%d", &h,&m,&s, &ms);
    std::cout << h << " " << m << " " << s << " " << ms << std::endl;
}
```

Ещё раз пишу - это очень грубое решение.

Люди делают это на базе [буста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874654/boost-date-time-parsing-string).

По поводу кода. Первое, что бросается в глаза - это переменная `newtime`. В нее не добавляют новые символы,  но зато обращаются по индексу. А это сразу приведет к ошибке. Второе - переменная `char* t_val;` объявлена, но память под строку не выделена. Это также приведет к ошибке.

Comment: Спасибо). А в моем коде из-за чего ошибка не знаете?

Comment: При таком кол-ве ошибок я не удивляюсь, что компилятор выдал именно такую ошибку.

Но я не совсем уверен, что я правильно понял, что должен делать код.

Comment: Ну вот весь код http://pastebin.com/wNV4tiU2  
Если char* t_val заменить на string t_val, то все работает. То есть не работает почему-то из за char *, хоть типы и разные, но я же их содержимое в цикле присваиваю, а не char к string. 
Суть программы в том, чтобы изменить время в файле субтитров, в котором строка времени выглядит так 00:00:00,299 --> 00:00:03,132  
Программа получилось такой, так как для себя и мало ещё знаний. Вообщем время на вводе должно четко соответствовать формату 00:00:00,000.

Comment: А тип char* использовал, потому что его требует параметр паблик функции getline, а нужна мне эта функция из-за возможности указать количество введенных символов, которые будут записаны.

Comment: если просто объявить переменную `char * x`, то это просто указатель. просто 4 байта (обычно). А Вам нужно ввести строку. Ее размер может быть разным. А где же ее хранить? Самый простой способ замените `char* t_val;` на `char t_val[256];` если 256 не хватит - добавьте больше.

Comment: @Robert Pinkman, если пишете в Linux, то советую посмотреть (`man 3 getline`)

       #include <stdio.h>
       ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);

Частенько весьма удобная функция для чтения строк неизвестной длины.

Comment: @avp: [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) есть и в стандарте.

Comment: @VladD, точно! Что-то я не обратил внимание на

           Since glibc 2.10:
               _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700
           Before glibc 2.10:
               _GNU_SOURCE

в том же man-е.

А вот по Вашим ссылкам - другие `getline()` (из С++). Посмотрите на сигнатуры.

Comment: @avp: И правда, не те сигнатуры. Но всё равно хорошо, что `getline` стандартизировали в POSIX, полезная вещь.